# Laravel : Email Jobs are not attempted

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-queue

i have my Laravel project setup on Ubuntu Server where emails are being sent using Jobs.

Below is my laravel-worker file in **/etc/supervisor/laravel-worker.conf**

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

My jobs are being dispatched in Controller as this

```
   dispatch(new UserRegistrationEmail($data, $token));
```

in env file i have

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

This was all working fine and emails were being sent in background but for some reason emails stopped going automatically and queues are not being attempted .  My Jobs table

[image]

if i am logged in through **Putty** and run command `php artisan queue:work`  it executes the jobs and emails are sent, Now until dont ctrl+c this command it keeps processing upcoming job requests as well , as seen in screenshot  .

I have cleared config cache, restarted queue, cleared cache but nothing helped. Can someone please help with this , This is quite frustrating

[image]

Comment: What is in the worker.log file?? Did you saw it?

Answer (score 1):

When you dispatch a job through the code (like  `App\Jobs\YourJob::dispatch();` ) It will create a record in the jobs table, with all the information needed to run this job.

Once you run `php artisan queue:work` it starting to fetch these jobs from the database, as a queue (the latest one first) and run the commands.

In order to monitor and fetch and run these jobs when they are presented in the database I use the command  `php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty` and run this command every minute in my webserver as a cron job.

In this case everyminute it checks the datebase and if there is any job to handle it does.

Comment: but my point is to run it through supervisor which is a standard way to manage queues and it was working fine , i am not sure why it stopped working